# Auto-expanding formula and then copy paste values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a function that adds an auto-expanding formula to some Header row cell

In the next line of code, I get the `Display Values` and then post them back to the sheet

I am concerned that I will be getting the values in the range of the auto-expanding formulas `before` they have finished `expanding`

Will this `r.getDisplayValues();` get the values `before` the auto-expansion has finished? thereby getting values with blank data that should have data

I have tested various scenarios, but this is not definitive

Also, I have not been able to find anything in searching on this

Thank you

```
function setFormulasAE_n() {
  var ss    =SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet =ss.getSheetByName('Elements');
  var LC    = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var LR    = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Auto-expanding Formulas to be added
  //Two dim array with 1 row
  var formulas = [[
"=ArrayFormula({\"ig_TagsHistorical\";iferror(vlookup(INDIRECT(\"Elements!A2:A\"&counta(Elements!$AJ$1:$AJ)), \'HelperElements_(ignore)\'!$A$2:$G, {5}, 0))})",
  "=ArrayFormula({\"Additional Networks\";iferror(vlookup(INDIRECT(\"Elements!A2:A\"&counta(Elements!$AJ$1:$AJ)), \'Helper_(ignore)\'!$A$2:$D, {4}, 0))})",
 ]];

  //Add auto-expanding formulas to Cell(s)
  var cell = sheet.getRange(1,LC+1,1,formulas[0].length);
  cell.setFormulas(formulas);

  //Get range and post back Display Values
  var r = sheet.getRange(1,LC+1,LR,formulas[0].length);
  var v = r.getDisplayValues();
  r.setValues(v)

}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Will this `r.getDisplayValues();` get the values `before` the auto-expansion has finished? thereby getting values with blank data that should have data

Comment: Perhaps you should try a SpreadsheetApp.flush() right after setFormulas().

Comment: Thanks, I will add that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setFormulas()` function you have used in the script is **synchronous** which essentially means that the code following the instruction **won't** be executed until the functions finishes the execution.

Therefore, `r.getDisplayValues()` will always get the values **after** the auto-expansion.

What you could do to make sure that the values you get are the expected ones is to use the `flush()` function after the `cell.setFormulas(formulas)` line of code. What `flush()` does is basically applying all the pending Spreadsheet changes - more specifically the formulas you need to set.

Furthermore, you can check these links since they might be of help to you:

- [SpreadsheetApp Class - flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush);
- [Range Class - setFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas).